# Encrypt password with PBEWithMD5AndDES and fetch data from DB gives a blank response

Tags: oracle, python-2.7, password-encryption

This is my code

```
def encrypt(q,_userEmail,password):
"""Mimic Java's PBEWithMD5AndDES algorithm to produce a DES key"""
_password = '111'
_salt = '\xA9\x9B\xC8\x32\x56\x35\xE3\x03'
_iterations = 19

plaintext_to_encrypt = password

hasher = MD5.new()
hasher.update(_password)
hasher.update(_salt)
result = hasher.digest()

for i in range(1, _iterations):
    hasher = MD5.new()
    hasher.update(result)
    result = hasher.digest()

# Pad plaintext per RFC 2898 Section 6.1
padding = 8 - len(plaintext_to_encrypt) % 8
plaintext_to_encrypt += chr(padding) * padding

encoder = DES.new(result[:8], DES.MODE_CBC, result[8:16])
encrypted = encoder.encrypt(plaintext_to_encrypt)
q.put(encrypted.encode('base64'))
pw = encrypted.encode('base64')
print str(pw)
cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute('''SELECT * FROM UTTARA_USER_MAST WHERE EMAIL_ID=:1 AND PASSWD=:2''',(_userEmail,str(pw),))
data=cur.fetchall()
print data
```

print str(pw) prints the encrypted password ,when i pass pw in a query 
the query returns blank but when i give the encrypted string directly in query it returns the data

edit: I use Oracle DB

Comment: What you're doing here is using a weak hashing algorithm and then retrieveably encrypting the hash... this doesn't make much sense. Look into using `bcrypt.hashpw` instead, it's designed for this.

Comment: Actually my server uses this algoritm so i need to encrypt the password from login screen and check with the data retreived